# In Ado.Net Update winth transaction "Concurrency violation"

Tags: mysql, concurrency, transactions, ado.net

I write on MySQL 5.5, C#, ADO.NET, DataSet. 
I have a DataSet and DataAdapter filled it. In DataAdapter I override INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE commands. When I use stored procedures, as these commands, all is well. 
However, when I use transactionns in this stored procedures, I get an exception:

> Concurrency violation: the DeleteCommand affected 0 of the expected 1 records.

What can I do with this errors?

Sample: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/46828938/DataGridSample.zip

To reproduce the problem: Delete row from Datagrid and press "Update" button.

> DBConcurrencyException ("Concurrency violation: the DeleteCommand affected 0 of the expected 1 records.") reproduce on:"productDataAdapter.Update(dataSet, "Products");" string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I learning a lot of documentations about this problem (msdn, mysql forum, stackoverflow, etc) and see:

Check real concurrency or not possibility do additional queries:

1. `insert`: get last inserted row and comparision with inserted row.
2. `update`: get updated row (by key for example) and comparision with updated row.
3. `delete`: try get row (by key for example) and get null.

Of course, all described above comparisions nessesary do in one logical bath / connection etc.
Unfortunately other way check '"Concurrency violation” or not on MySql' isn't exist. (In defference from others db servers).

I hope, that this information helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

```
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("insert into student_info values(@id,@name,@batch)",con);
        com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@id", dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value));
        com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@name", dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value) );
        com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@batch", dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value));
        da.InsertCommand = com;


        com = new SqlCommand("update student_info set name = @name, batch = @batch where s_id = @id", con);
        com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@id", dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value));
        com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@name", dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value));
        com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@batch", dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value));
        da.UpdateCommand = com;

        com = new SqlCommand("delete from student_info where s_id = @id", con);
        com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@id", dataGridView1.Rows[(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index -1)].Cells[0].Value));
```

Are you using the above approach? Fortunately I've found out the reason for this exception but still looking for answer.
Error arises because we are using CurrentRow property of dataGridView. It works fine with insert and update command. But when we pick the cuurentRow for delete command, datagridview actually picks up the next row. If next record exists then it gets deleted , otherwise it throws an error like this. I'm still looking for an answer.. By the time you may use CommandBuilder, it works fine.